# Stuck in repair tool loop Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ssd, windows-update, dell-inspiron

Today I decided to install an update on Dell Inspiron 14 5000.
After the restart, it put me in the repair tool loop and none of the options presented in troubleshooting work. Furthermore, when I try to run "C:" in cmd, it says it cannot find the drive, however, when I open up BIOS settings it does see the SSD drive. The SSD drive is not the original drive that was in the laptop, but everything was working fine up until now. How can I fix the issue?

edit: I don't exactly recall what update it was, but it had to be either Dell-related or Windows Update

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: "install an update" - what update?

Comment: You need to remove the SSD and install into another computer to see if you can access it via whatever drive letter gets assigned. Are you able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> however, when I open up BIOS settings it does see the my SSD drive.
> The SSD drive is not the original drive that was in the laptop, but
> everything was working fine up until now.

Get the SSD Manufacturer's Drive Test App (e.g. Samsung Magician tools) on a bootable USB Key and test the drive.

Startup loops like you see are (in my experience) either (a) a bad drive or (b) a badly corrupted operating system.

If the latter and Windows Startup repair does not fix it, you will have to reinstall the operating system.

If the former, you will need to replace the drive and then reinstall Windows.